# Ruby - open CSV file for reading and writing

Tags: ruby, csv

I want to open a CSV file from Ruby and add a new column which has a value based on the values of existing columns. I want to do something like this:

```
CSV.foreach(newf) do |row|
    if(last_row != nil)
      row << (row[CR_RATE_COL].to_f - last_row[CR_RATE_COL].to_f)/last_row[CR_RATE_COL].to_f
    end
    last_row = row
  end
```

However, this code doesn't change the file which I've opened(because it only reads).
Is there a way to both read and write in a file?

Comment: Please don't put your tags in your title. You already put them in the tags section.

Answer (score 0):

you need to persist the data to a file. you're only modifying it in memory.

use a separate array in which you are storing the rows.
At the end do a CSV.generate with that array:
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0.preview1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-generate

see writing => to a file in that section for full example